# powershell ExecutionPolicy is not setting properly

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, policy, powershell-cmdlet

I am running powershell from batch script. Here is sample code.

```
   powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
   set logDir=C:\testfolder\
   mkdir %logDir%
   powershell.exe C:\<folder>\test.ps1 >> "%logDir%test.log"
```

Getting error: "test.ps1" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
This issue occurred only on particular VM. The same script execution completes on other windows machines.
Need solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

whenever I want powershell.exe to execute a ps1 file I use the following syntax:

```
powershell.exe -f "C:\<folder>\test.ps1"
```

telling the exe to execute a file not a Cmdlet.